# AutoHotKey: Remap mouse middle button to ctrl

Tags: autohotkey

How to remap mouse middle button `MButton` to `ctrl`, expecting normal ctrl behavior (`MButton Hold` like `Ctrl Hold`).

Comment: See [Remapping Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#RemapMouse).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs the code, I've achieved it by:

```
MButton::Ctrl
```